# How to see all the TCP connections opened by Google Chrome browser on Mac?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, browser, tcp, netstat

I am currently browsing using the Google Chrome browser. I know that for every tab I open and type a URL in, a TCP connection is opened. I also know that a maximum of 6 concurrent TCP connections are given to a single domain.

However I don't know where can I can look up this information of all TCP connections opened by Google Chrome browser.

I tried to use the netstat command to list all TCP connections. However I was unable to understand which connections are related to the Google Chrome browser.

Comment: Try `nettop`. Tip: Make your terminal window as wide as it will go if you want to see all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game but,

```
sudo lsof -n -i TCP | grep Google
```